# UITableView very slow scrolling with images from the web

Tags: iphone

I am loadingimages from a url it's about 20-30 images over http.

The UITableView is very very slow sticky.

What can i do to make it smother?

Comment: How are you loading the images in your cellForRowAtIndex and are you reusing the cells?

Comment: yes im using cellforrowatindex to load images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download them first, then cache them.

If the cell needs to display and the image isn't there yet, have a placeholder image available until the real one shows up.

If it's still slow after that, hook up Instruments and profile it. Instruments will tell you exactly where your code is spending all its time.

Comment: the images are displaying in the cells fine, but scrolling is very slow. SO I assume they are already downloaded even if i wait 2-3 minutes the scrolling is still slow

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities:

1. Are you keeping the entire image in
   memory and scaling it down when you
   draw the cell? That will slow things
   down considerably; consider scaling
   the image to icon size and
   discarding the original image. You
   can always reload it.
2. UITableViewCells are notorious for
   being slow if you have more than a
   couple of subviews. The best
   solution to this problems is drawing
   the cell yourself in the cell's
   drawRect: method.

BJ's placeholder idea is a great suggestion, downloading the image in the background as you can and replacing the placeholders as they complete.

Comment: what is the best way to download files in the background